Issues with a basic voltage to frequency converter
I've been having some trouble getting my below voltage to frequency converter to work as intended. Before anyone says this, I will say that I expect the frequency to be non-linear in proportion to the voltage and am simply using it to maintain isolation between my microcontroller and high voltage components. The nonlinearity can easily be corrected in software (I only need a precision of ±10V).

Instead of a waveform with varying frequency dependent on the input voltage to the voltage divider, the astable 555 timer is outputting a plain 5V signal no matter what Vin is set to.
I have previously had success with a similar circuit I had prototyped on a breadboard, which I thought had been transcribed to a schematic well but evidently after rebuilding it something has been lost in translation.
Could someone please check what I have done wrong with the schematic here?

If the input voltage is below 3.3333 volts how can you expect it to work?

if you have a microcontroller at hand, why the whole frequency modulation complication on the HV side? dual octocoupler, one going from MCU to HV side, one the other way. MCU pulses the optocoupler (or a MOSFET gate attached to it) to discharge a capacitor. Capacitor gets charged through resistor from high voltage. Comparator on the HV side compares capacitor voltage to reference voltage. when cap > ref, it turns on the other optocoupler. MCU measures how long charging takes, discharges capacitor. (Do that in a loop and you're also doing a voltage-to-frequency conversion, but here you're …

relying on a precisely controllable reference voltage (e.g. from the venerable TL431 or a REF35 or such) rather than some random tolerances inside the NE555. You can operate with much lower supply voltage; if you want to be smart, instead of a comparator + precision voltage source, you can just buy an undervoltage supervision IC (do note that a lot of them have delays intentionally built in!) like the TLV840 to watch when the capacitor voltage becomes high enough. That would effectively reduce your part count to 1 dual-optocoupler, 1 voltage supervisor, 1 capacitor.

@MarcusMüller Thanks for the help. The reference voltage + capacitor-based design seems interesting, would you happen to have any resources/know where I could best find resources on these concepts? I haven't used anything like the TLV840 before.

@poxyping all I can quickly think of is already in that comment above :) You might want to simply start with the datasheet of the TLV840 and read on what it does.

The 555 provides pin CV (control voltage) to alter the switching threshold voltage, for voltage-to-frequency conversion. It seems very dicey to rely on $V_{IN}$, since that will determine maximum C1 voltage; you need to keep that well above $\frac{2}{3}V_{CC}$. Any reason why you didn't use CV?

There is no "Vin" on the schematic.  Do you mean "voltmeter"?

@AnalogKid there isn't a $V_{IN}$ now, there was (at least it looked like $V_{IN}$, the font is so fat it was hard to read), at the bottom of R2, but the schematic has changed. R37, R38 and "voltmeter" are new (if I recall correctly)

Driving the top of the timing divider with a variable voltage is risky, with a very limited workable voltage range.  At this time, the values of R37 and R38 are waaaaay off.
